# BRST quantization and physical states (Polchinski)

Tags: string-theory, hilbert-space, conservation-laws, brst

I'm reading section 4.2 of Polchinski's string theory vol. 1. In the page 131, there are sentences

> "In fact, only states $\mid k,\downarrow  \rangle$ satisfying the additional condition $ b\mid \psi \rangle =0 $ appear in physical amplitudes. The origin of this additional condition is kinematic. For $ k^2+m^2 \neq 0 $, the states $\mid k,\uparrow  \rangle$ are exact - they are orthogonal to all physical states and their amplitudes must vanish identically. So the amplitudes can only be proportional to  $\delta (k^2+m^2) $. But amplitudes in field theory and string theory, while they may have poles and cuts, never have delta functions (except in $D=2$ where kinematics is special)."

I don't understand why field theory and string theory do not have amplitudes proportional to $\delta (k^2+m^2) $ except $D=2$. I don't understand how kinematics explain the remarks above.

I think two dimensional field theories do not have any preference on position because of conformal symmetry. In case of the other dimensional field theories, however, there are the preference. Therefore, I think field theory and string theory do not allow Dirac delta functional amplitudes. Am I right?